# Codeigniter type of button can't insert into database

Tags: php, codeigniter, insert

all data insert into database already , but field city_case doesn't insert , if I replace this field by another filed such as act_id , it insert correctly , Iam sure the problem in this field in view/add.php

```js
in controllers / cases.php


function add(){
  $data['fields_clients'] = $this->custom_field_model->get_custom_fields(1);
  $data['fields']    = $this->custom_field_model->get_custom_fields(2);
  $data['clients']   = $this->cases_model->get_all_clients();
  $data['stages']    = $this->case_stage_model->get_all();
  $data['acts']     = $this->cases_model->get_all_acts();
  $data['courts']    = $this->cases_model->get_all_courts();
  $data['locations']    = $this->cases_model->get_all_locations();
  $data['case_categories'] = $this->cases_model->get_all_case_categories();
  $data['court_categories']= $this->cases_model->get_all_court_categories();
                $data['city'] = $this->cases_model->get_name_city();
                //$data['employee'] = $this->cases_model->get_name_employee();
  if ($this->input->server('REQUEST_METHOD') === 'POST')
        { 
   $this->load->library('form_validation');
   $this->form_validation->set_message('required', lang('custom_required'));
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'lang:title', 'required');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('client_id', 'Client', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('case_no', 'Case No', '');        //trim|required|is_unique[cases.case_no]
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('location_id', 'Location', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('case_stage_id', 'Case Stage', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('court_id', 'Court', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('court_category_id', 'Court Category', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('case_category_id', 'Case Category', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('act_id', 'Act', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('start_date', 'Filing Date', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Description', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('city_case', 'city case', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('fees', 'Fees', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('o_lawyer', 'Opposite Lawyer', '');
   $this->form_validation->set_rules('hearing_date', 'Description', '');
    
   if ($this->form_validation->run()==true)
            {
    $save['title'] = $this->input->post('title');
    $save['case_no'] = $this->input->post('case_no');
    $save['client_id'] = $this->input->post('client_id');
    $save['location_id'] = $this->input->post('location_id');
    $save['court_id'] = $this->input->post('court_id');
    $save['court_category_id'] = $this->input->post('court_category_id');
    $save['case_stage_id'] = $this->input->post('case_stage_id');
    $save['case_category_id'] = json_encode($this->input->post('case_category_id'));
    $save['act_id'] = json_encode($this->input->post('act_id'));
    $save['description'] = $this->input->post('description');
    $save['start_date'] = $this->input->post('start_date');
    $save['hearing_date'] = $this->input->post('hearing_date');
    $save['o_lawyer'] = $this->input->post('o_lawyer');
    $save['fees'] = $this->input->post('fees');
    $save['city_case'] = json_encode($this->input->post('city_case'));
             
     $p_key = $this->cases_model->save($save);
    $reply = $this->input->post('reply');
     if(!empty($reply)){
     foreach($this->input->post('reply') as $key => $val) {
      $save_fields[] = array(
       'custom_field_id'=> $key,
       'reply'=> $val,
       'table_id'=> $p_key,
       'form'=> 2,
      ); 
     
     } 
     $this->custom_field_model->save_answer($save_fields);
    }
    
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', lang('case_created'));
    redirect('admin/cases');
   
    
   }
  }  
  
  
  $data['page_title'] = lang('add') . lang('case');
  $data['body'] = 'case/add';
  
  
  $this->load->view('template/main', $data); 

 }
```

```css
models / cases_model.php


function get_name_city ()
 {
  $query = $this->db->get ('user_role');
  return $query->result();
 }
```

```html
this is code I sure the problem in it  

<select name="city_case[]" class="chzn col-md-12" multiple="multiple" >
<option value="">--<?php echo lang('select_city')?>--</option> <?php foreach($city as $new) { $sel = ""; if(set_select('city_case', $new->id)) $sel = "selected='selected'"; echo '<option value="'.$new->id.'" '.$sel.'>'.$new->name.'</option>'; }?>
  </select>


I replace it with this code , it work well 

<input type="text" name="city_case" class="form-control" value="<?php echo set_value('city_case'); ?>">
```

, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line to

```
$save['city_case'] = json_encode($this->input->post('city_case'));
```

To

```
$save['city_case'] = json_encode($this->input->post('city_case[]'));
```

Comment: Thank you , it'is worked well , and it work well 
as $save['city_case'] = json_encode($this->input->post('city_case'));